# fwrite skipping data

Tags: c

When I use `fwrite` inside this block of code, it skips the read of data:

```
void corregirColeccionSumas(FILE *pfbSumas, int *nmal, int *nbien) {
    T_SUMA estaSuma;
    do {
        fread(&estaSuma, 1, sizeof(T_SUMA), pfbSumas);
        if (!feof(pfbSumas)) {
            corregirSuma(&estaSuma);
            //fwrite(&estaSuma, sizeof(T_SUMA), 1, pfbSumas);

            mostrarSuma(estaSuma);

            if (SUMA_BIEN == estaSuma.correccion) {
                (*nbien)++;
            } else {
                (*nmal)++;
            }
        }
    } while (!feof(pfbSumas));
}
```

With no `fwrite` it outputs:

```
1 + 2 = 4 correccion = M
2 + 2 = 4 correccion = B
4 + 2 = 6 correccion = B
5 + 3 = 53 correccion = M
10 + 2 = 12 correccion = B
```

With `fwrite` it outputs:

```
1 + 2 = 4 correccion = M
4 + 2 = 6 correccion = B
10 + 2 = 12 correccion = B
```

Note that it outputs the odd lines, skipping the even ones. It seems like it consumes the data.

I also wrote this code by using `while (!feof(pfbSumas))` and it didn't change the behaviour.

Also, this file was opened with the `rb+` mode.

In order to be tested, this function was rewritten like this:

```
void corregirColeccionSumas(FILE *pfbSumas, int *nmal, int *nbien) {
    int estaSuma;
    int leidos = fread(&estaSuma, 1, sizeof(int), pfbSumas);
    while (leidos != 0) {
        estaSuma = 34;
        fseek(pfbSumas, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        fwrite(&estaSuma, sizeof(int), 1, pfbSumas);
        fflush(pfbSumas);
        printf("%d\n", estaSuma);

        leidos = fread(&estaSuma, 1, sizeof(int), pfbSumas);
    }
}
```

Its output was:

```
34
34
34
```

Previously to this function, this snippet of code was written to write initial data:

```
 for(int nSuma = 0; nSuma < 5; nSuma++) {
        fwrite(&nSuma, sizeof (int), 1, pfbSumas);
 }
```

As forementioned, the `frwite` function skips data.

I modified this line:`(pfbSumas, -4, SEEK_CUR);`
to write `-4` and it works (it shows the five numbers) but I don't know which value I should write to show my T_SUMA values.

Comment: You can replace the T_SUMA type with an int, for example. Also, the functions 'corregirSumas', 'mostrarSuma' and the if section don't interfere with the issue.

Comment: You repeat the condition `if (!feof(pfbSumas))` in the loop `do {} while (!feof(pfbSumas))`, there is no purpose for such do while, should be a while instead, without the if. Also you don't provide T_SUMA struct

Comment: Use `fseek()` before the write and `fflush()` after the write. Don't use `feof()`, use the return value from `fread()` to control the loop. It is given for a reason. And please read [`fopen()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-160) - the rules in the section about file opening modes.

Comment: ... which says "When the "r+", "w+", or "a+" access type is specified, both reading and writing are enabled (the file is said to be open for "update"). However, when you ***switch from reading to writing***, the input operation must encounter an EOF marker. If there is no EOF, you must use an intervening call to a file positioning function. The file positioning functions are fsetpos, fseek, and rewind. When you ***switch from writing to reading***, you must use an intervening call to either fflush or to a file positioning function."

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL, I checked that code with the `while (!feof(...))` version and it outputs the same result.

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: you should use r+ instead of rb, why b, do you have any binary data?

Comment: I have updated the last function (minimalistic function) in order to add your suggestions: `fseek`, change the `eof` by `leidos != 0`.

It still continues to show only 3 out of 5 lines.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL, yes, it is a binary file.

Comment: Thanks, @WeatherVane: I have changed that statement. Please, check my code out.

Comment: Please use this loop: `while(fread(&estaSuma, sizeof(T_SUMA), 1, pfbSumas) == 1) {...}` and you have still omitted to `fflush()` after `fwrite()`.

Answer (score 0):

The fwrite will update the pointer. You should do rewind after fwrite.

Comment: I wrote a rewind after fwrite but infinite loop was executed.

Comment: Have you tried also with fseek() ?Also,  I'm not sure if you will have interference with fread and fwrite I/O buffers, try to flush to a log file `tail -f debug.log` to see what is happening.

Comment: I updated my code by adding that function. Please, check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
void corregirColeccionSumas(FILE *pfbSumas, int *nmal, int *nbien) {
    T_SUMA estaSuma;
    int i;
    int ctrl;
    rewind(pfbSumas);
    i = 0;
    do {
        ctrl = fread(&estaSuma, sizeof(T_SUMA), 1, pfbSumas);
        if (ctrl == 1) {
            corregirSuma(&estaSuma);
            fseek(pfbSumas, (long)(i * sizeof (T_SUMA)), SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&estaSuma, sizeof(T_SUMA), 1, pfbSumas);
            mostrarSuma(estaSuma);
            if (SUMA_BIEN == estaSuma.correccion) {
                (*nbien)++;
            } else {
                (*nmal)++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    } while (ctrl == 1);
}
```